# Reading Binary Files Using Bitwise Shifters and Buffers in C++

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm trying to read a binary file and simple convert the data to usable unsigned integers. The code below works for 2-byte reading, for certain file locations, and correctly prints the unsigned integer. When I use the 4-byte code though my value turns out to be a number much larger than it is supposed to be. I believe the issue lies within the read function, it seems as though I am getting the wrong character/decimal number (101 for example) which when bit shifted becomes a number much larger than it should be (~6662342).(when the program runs it throws an exception every now and then "stack around the variable buf runtime error #2" in visual studios). Any ideas? It may be my fundamental knowledge of how the data is stored in the char array that is affecting my data output.

working 2-byte code

```
unsigned char buf[2];
    file.seekg(3513);
    uint64_t value = readBufferLittleEndian(buf, &file);

    printf("%i", value);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}


uint64_t readBufferLittleEndian(unsigned char buf[], std::ifstream *file)
{
    file->read((char*)(&buf[0]), 2);
    return (buf[1] << 8 | buf[0]);
}
```

broken 4-byte code

```
unsigned char buf[8 + 1]; //= { 0, 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0 };
    uint64_t buf1[9];
    file.seekg(3213);
    uint64_t value = readBufferLittleEndian(buf, &file, buf1);

    std::cout << value;


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}


uint64_t readBufferLittleEndian(unsigned char buf[], std::ifstream *file, uint64_t buf1[])
{
    file->read((char*)(&buf[0]), 4);
    for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        buf1[index] = buf[index];
    }
    buf1[0];
    buf1[1];
    buf1[2];
    buf1[3];
    //return (buf1[7] << 56 | buf1[6] << 48 | buf1[5] << 40 | buf1[4] << 32 | buf1[3] << 24 | buf1[2] << 16 | buf1[1] << 8 | buf1[0]);
    return (buf1[3] << 24 | buf1[2] << 16 | buf1[1] << 8 | buf1[0]);
    //return (buf1[1] << 8 | buf1[0]);
}
Please correct me if I got the endianess reversed.
```

code is C++ except for the printf line

Comment: It prints out negative values because you're using the wrong format. Also, don't mix C and C++ (so, use `std::cout` instead of `printf`).

Comment: I thought it might be as simple as changing all the bit shifts to 8, instead of the factors of 8, but this prints a number lower than expected.

Comment: What would the correct format be sorry

Comment: "stack around the variable buf runtime error #2" has nothing to do with bit shifts

Comment: I assumed it mean that I tried to access bits around the buf that did not belong to the buf. Also I only get that error when I add more bit shifters, so I thought that was a fair assumption.

Comment: Plus a google search afterwards indicates this error would also be thrown if you try to access an index of an array that is out of bounds. So I am fairly certain it has to do with the bit shifts

Comment: nothing to do with bit shifts.

Comment: @pm100 could you actually explain what the error is then

Comment: cast the individual `buf[n]` terms to `uint64_t`  Also, printf is assuming whatever size your `int` is, not necessarily a 64 bit one.

Comment: `%i` is going to treat the argument as a signed integer, which is likely 32 bit on your platform. Change it to `std::cout << value;`

Comment: specified length and changed the specifier for printf. Also I figure the for loop should do the same as a cast. I made it before you mentioned casting @doug. Still get crazy large numbers for byte starting points in the file. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to cast the char to a unit64 before shifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seekg(0) = byte 1, seekg(3212) = byte 3213. Not entirely sure why I was getting a zero in byte 3214 before, considering I now get 220 (indicating big-endianess). Getting 220 would have indicated that I was interpreting the functionality of seekg(). Oh well it is solved where it matters now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you have to cast before shifting. You cannot shift a char left 56 bits.

ie do `((uint64_t)buf[n] << NN`

Comment: If I've done a "manual" cast with the second array buf1[] should it not fix this already. If I watch the indices of buf1[] they print out the correct binary shifted value. It almost seems as though there is something wrong with the read function.

Comment: For example when I'm following the second index of buf, it is assigned 101 'whatever character 101 is'. Then after assigning this value to my uint64_t array the second index is just 101. I can then properly bit shift. However 101 is not the right answer in the first place. It may just be that my fundamental concept of the byte storage in these arrays is wrong.

Comment: you are now describing different programs, hard to comment without seeing them. Do this, get rid of read, by hand setup 8 byte array (with lterals) and see what happens. Also just try shifting one byte by various amounts, see what happens, there is no voodoo magic here

Comment: Tested the bit shifting with a hand setup 4-byte & 8-byte array, it definitely works. The only problem now is when reading the file I should get {220,5,0,0} at position 3513, however buf[0]  = 0 buf[1] = 101 'e', buf1[1] = 101. So it must be something wrong with my understanding of the read function. Am I wrong in assuming it evaluates the bits in each byte and stores them as a character/value.

Comment: note that you are not testing to see if the read worked - you could have garbage

Comment: There is a test to see if the file opened correctly, just cut that bit out. I believe the read *works* as it does output the same values every time. Not random